# namespaceError running DNN website

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to Dot Net Nuke (DNN). I am currently running the latest version of DNN.

When I go to build the site I get this:

> The type or namespace name 'Internal does not exist in the namespace 'DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any idea what the problem may be?

ERRORS:

[Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ8fG.png)

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yypMT.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "build"? You don't need to BUILD DNN in order to run the site in IIS

Comment: I'm building a project (web site) in DNN and I'm trying to run it in Visual Studio

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do... Where do you get that error. Can you show the method/relevant code?

Comment: I have update the original post, adding the errors I am getting. I am attempting to view the website in the browser.

Comment: Okay, but to USE DNN you don't need to BUILD anything. You can just use the INSTALL zip file.

Comment: Yes, Correct. However, when I go to view the "deault.aspx" page I get those errors.

Comment: That's because you didn't use the "INSTALL" package. Your best bet would be to start over using the INSTALL package

Comment: @ChrisHammond Thanks! I forgot all about the install package.